# how to get the return of array sended to one ajax in the datatable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

Hi people of stackoverflow

I'm using the datatable for to show of data of my tables... and I need to make some custom filters at the same time. I basically, until then, I'm sending the request as follows:

```
 $('#btnFiltro').on( 'click', function () {   // for text boxes
      var dados = new Array();
      $('#frmReportPartners').find(":text:visible,:checkbox:checked,select:visible").each(function(v) {
          dados[v] = $(this).val();
     });
     dataTable.columns().search(dados).draw();
     console.log(dados);
 });
```

Now, after this submission, what form should I use to be able to retrieve and handle such submitted information, since I only record one, I get like this:

```
if(!empty($requestData['columns'][10]['search']['value'])) {
    $sql .= " AND data_de_aluguel LIKE '" . $requestData['columns'][10]['search']['value'] . "%'";
}
```

My English may have gotten a little bad, but I hope to understand.

Thank you